# tf.keras model.predict each time provides different values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Each time I run:

```
y_true = np.argmax(tf.concat([y for x, y in train_ds], axis=0), axis=1)
y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(train_ds), axis=1)

confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

The result each time is different to my understanding the line:
`y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(train_ds), axis=1)` is different each time.

Clarification: I run cell 1 (training) once. And cell 2 (inference) few times.

**Why?**

**THE CODE:**
**Cell 1** (jupyter)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, experimental
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dense 
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


image_size = (100, 100)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    label_mode='categorical',
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=1337,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)


inputs = Input(shape =(100,100,1))
x = experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(inputs)
x = Conv2D (filters =4, kernel_size =3, padding ='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D (filters =4, kernel_size =3, padding ='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size =2, strides =2, padding ='same')(x)

x = Conv2D (filters =8, kernel_size =3, padding ='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D (filters =8, kernel_size =3, padding ='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size =2, strides =2, padding ='same')(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(units = 4, activation ='relu')(x)
x = Dense(units = 4, activation ='relu')(x)
output = Dense(units = 5, activation ='softmax')(x)

model = Model (inputs=inputs, outputs =output)

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3),
    loss=categorical_crossentropy,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=5)
```

**Cell 2**:

```
print (Accuracy:)
y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(train_ds), axis=1)
print (accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))

y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(train_ds), axis=1)
print (accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

**OUTPUT**:

118/118 [==============================] - 7s 57ms/step - loss: 0.1888 - accuracy: 0.9398

Accuracy:

0.593

0.586

Comment: So, you don't set any seed? And no model saving?

Comment: There is a seed in dataset generation.
But I run it in a different cell in Jupiter. Training in one cell and inference in another cell.
I've got your point. I will update the code description.

Comment: What do you mean each time? Are you running the whole script? Because in your code the model.predict only runs once.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, Now I've updated the code / cell splitting. I don't run the whole script once.
I've run model fitting 1 time and few times inference (model.predict) and each time there is a different prediction, with significantly worse accuracy.

Comment: That is hard to believe since there is no stochastic components in your model (like MC-Dropout), so maybe you need to provide evidence of how the predictions are different (including values).

Comment: And probably you should put model.predict in its own cell to make sure other things are not interfering, and then make multiple runs of it.

Comment: model.predict and rest of the code are in different cells.
For me it's also hard to believe.

Comment: Can you update the question with 2 runs? How the predictions and accuracy differ exactly?

Comment: @Frightera. Code & Output updated.

Comment: Try to iterate over the dataset once to obtain preds and real classes. Please check [tf-accuracy-score-and-confusion-matrix-disagree-is-tensorflow-shuffling-data-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672375/tf-accuracy-score-and-confusion-matrix-disagree-is-tensorflow-shuffling-data-on/66673772#66673772)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I think got the reason. See the suggested solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my current understanding the reason of an above is the:

`tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`

While instance of it is:

`type(train_ds)`

> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset

Reproduction:

**First run:**

`[x for x, y in train_ds]`

Output:

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(32, 100, 100, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=  array([[[[157.],
          [155.],
          [159.],
```

**Second run:**

`[x for x, y in train_ds]`

Output:

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(32, 100, 100, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=  array([[[[ 34.],
          [ 36.],
          [ 39.],
          ...,
```

**The possible solution**

```
imgs, y_true = [], []
for img, label in train_ds:
    imgs.append(img)
    y_true.append(label)

imgs = tf.concat(imgs, axis=0)    
y_true = np.argmax(tf.concat(y_true, axis=0), axis=1)

y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(imgs), axis=1)
print (accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))

y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(imgs), axis=1)
print (accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0.944044764
0.944044764
```

**Is there any better solution?**

### UPDATE 2:

Maybe more appropriate apporach in case of validation dataset (here the `train_ds` is just for example is to add an argument `Shuffle=False`)

```
    train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
        directory,
        label_mode='categorical',
        validation_split=0.2,
        subset="training",
        seed=1337,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        image_size=image_size,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        Shuffle=False

    )
```

#### UPDATE 3:

##### Here it's probably the best option in case if your `test images` are in a separate folder.

```
path = 'your path to test folder'


test_generator = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    directory=path,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=32,
    target_size=(512, 512)
)

test_generator.reset()
```

This is better than OPTION 1, since it can work on dataset, which doesn't fits into memory (RAM).

Comment: did you find any improvement for the above code?

Comment: @OmarIsmail, just added another option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you do not train the model again every time you run the code? If the parameters of the model are the same the predicted result for the same input should be the same every time.

Comment: Code splitted into 2 cells (in the jupyter notebook).
First cell for training. Second cell for inference.
I run cell (1) one time and cell (2) few times.