# How to get labels for confusion matrix from image_dataset_from_directory in keras

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build the confusion matrix and classification report using keras but I am going wrong somewhere. Specifically, it looks lile I am not pulling correct labels from the `image_dataset_from_directory` object. The code I am using is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import pathlib
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Rescaling
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# get data and preprocess
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)


img_height = 180
img_width = 180

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=256)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=32)

class_names = train_ds.class_names

train_labels = np.concatenate([y for x, y in train_ds], axis=0)
train_labels1 = np.concatenate([y for x, y in train_ds], axis=0)  # repull traiing labels

validation_labels = np.concatenate([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)
validation_labels1 = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0).numpy()  # repull validation labels

# AUTOTUNE
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

# Build model
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.001),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit  model
model_output = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10 ,validation_data=(val_ds), verbose=0)

# Predict and generate confusion matrix and classification report
prediction = model.predict(val_ds)
score = model.evaluate(val_ds, verbose=0)
validation_pred = np.argmax(prediction, axis = 1)
cm = confusion_matrix(validation_labels, validation_pred)

plt.figure(figsize=(9,9))
sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt=".3f", linewidths=.5, square = True, cmap = 'Blues_r', yticklabels=class_names, xticklabels=class_names)
plt.ylabel('Actual label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
all_sample_title = f'Model Accuracy Score: {score[1]:.2%}'
plt.title(all_sample_title, size = 15)

print(classification_report(validation_labels, validation_pred, target_names=class_names))
```

and I get a confusion matrix and classification report for the validation dataset that looks like just a random guess and does not correspond to the validation accuracy:

[image: confusion matrix]
[image: classification report]

In the above code, I pulled the labels from the object for validation dataset:

```
validation_labels = np.concatenate([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)
validation_labels1 = tf.concat([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0).numpy()
```

and they are different each time I pull them whereas I would expect them to be the same:
[image: validation labels]

Where am I going wrong, does the `shuffle=True` change the labels every time I access the `val_ds` object?

Comment: *does the shuffle=True change the labels every time?*: Yes.

Comment: I get the part when I create the object why it shuffles, but does it when I access it too? For example, if I try to get the labels using `validation_labels = np.concatenate([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)` and `validation_labels1 = np.concatenate([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)`, `validation_labels` and `validation_labels1` are not the same. Is that because they get reshuffled when I access the object?

Comment: Yes, it is reshuffled in every iteration.

Comment: In that case, what is the recommended way to create a confusion matrix that matches true labels to predicted labels if it reshuffles every time? Presumably, when I create true `validation_labels` and then run the prediction on`val_ds` to create `validation_pred`, I am accessing `val_ds` twice so the indexes will not match since the data is reshuffled twice.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66673772/13726668